# compiling mosquitto 1.4 with websockets on windows

Tags: windows, build, mosquitto

I got a problem compiling `mosquitto 1.4` with websockets set to on
I have the following cmake line:

```
cmake .. -DWITH_THREADING:BOOL=OFF -DWITH_WEBSOCKETS=ON
```

That will generate a nice `mosquitto.sln` for visual studio, but now I'm missing `libwebsocket.h`!

So the question is, what is the easiest way to get websocket installed on Windows and then get mosquitto to build?

Comment: CMake helps you to configure the project, it does not build your library. For that you should open the project generated by CMake and build that .

Answer (score 1):

You need to download and compile libwebsockets first and then use the provided libwebsockets.h and compiled libwebsockets.lib/.dll when you are building mosquitto.

https://libwebsockets.org/